# Should we ever close a question as "Primarily Opinion Based" on meta?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, meta, primarily-opinion-based

[What are the "must read" comics/issues from the following publishers?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6605/19561) received a close vote with the reason "Primarily Opinion Based". But on meta, we're *asking* for opinions.

Shouldn't that close reason be removed from meta?

---

I want to stress the point that that question isn't just asking for what to read, but for what the community would be interested in, regarding a review of the service.

Comment: [Same question on the main Stack Exchange meta site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191773/vote-to-close-as-primarily-opinion-based-on-meta)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions like this should generally be closed under the first off-topic reason:

> This question does not appear to be about Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network within the scope defined in the help center.

While I won't go so far as to say the primarily-opinion-based reason should never be used on meta, I have difficulty imagining a situation in which it would be appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Strikes me that it's a useful shortcut. Otherwise we'd need a close reason on meta for "This question belongs on the main site" and then have to close it again as opinion-based on the main site. I guess it could be rephrased as "This question would belong on the main site, but it's opinion-based and so off-topic there".