# Why was this meta question closed as opinion based?

Tags: discussion, support

This meta question was closed as opinion based:
[Who do you like most on SFF.SE?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10782/who-do-you-like-most-on-sff-se)

But, these meta questions are well received here:

[The many avatars of SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/the-many-avatars-of-sff-se)

[The many usernames of SFF:SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7371/the-many-usernames-of-sffse)

Why?

Comment: Because those are asking for personal explanations (if fluff), and yours is asking for personal opinions?

Comment: "why did you pick your avatar/username?" is not an opinion, it's a personal anecdote. There'a a huge difference. Plus, your question is pretty clearly an attempt to place certain users "above" other users. That's not nice.

Answer (score 6):

Because you *were* asking for opinions; you were asking the users for their opinions of other users.

The questions you compare yours two are **not** asking for opinions, but for explanations: were does a username or an avatar come from. While they *are* list questions, they're not opinion based.

---

Also, asking users to rate each other is not constructive.

Comment: You might also want to mention the potential for hurt feelings (downvoting answers, for example) as well as the slightly odd wording "*If you like me, I'll appreciate it, but I won't marry you.*" that could some across as slightly inappropriate.

Comment: Related: [Should we ever close a question as “Primarily Opinion Based” on meta?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6607/31394)

Comment: @Randal'Thor, yeah well, I don't know what **ID 10-T** asked that, but the answer is obviously "yes". :)